# Best aproach to Ground level detection for spells/skills

Tags: unity, raycasting

I'm making a 3d Hero Defense/Tower defense kind of game with unity3d. A made a skill system with scriptable objects that lets the Defender use skills on the terrain doing damage to enemies that can be damaged. Because of the complexity of the terrain in some parts (slopes going up or down) i made a function to detect ground level like this:

```
protected float GetGroundPosition(Vector3 position)
{
    LayerMask GroundLayer = 1 << GROUND_LAYER;
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    Physics.Raycast(position, -transform.up, out hitInfo, GROUND_DETECT_DISTANCE, GroundLayer);
    if (hitInfo.collider != null)
    {
        return hitInfo.point.y;
    }
    else
    {
        Physics.Raycast(position, transform.up, out hitInfo, GROUND_DETECT_DISTANCE, GroundLayer);
        return hitInfo.point.y;
    }
}
```

Then i subdivided my raycast in several small ones like this:

```
protected void DealBaseDamageInALine(Vector3 cursorPosition, float slashSize)
{
    List<GameObject> alreadyHit = new List<GameObject>();
    Vector3 startRaycast = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, GetGroundPosition(transform.position), transform.localPosition.z);
    for (int i = 1; i <= GROUND_COLLISION_RAYCAST_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        Vector3 endRaycast = startRaycast + transform.forward * (config.GetAoe() / (i * 2));
        endRaycast = new Vector3(endRaycast.x, GetGroundPosition(endRaycast), endRaycast.z);
        Debug.DrawLine(startRaycast, endRaycast, Color.blue, .5f);
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.CapsuleCastAll(startRaycast, endRaycast, slashSize, Vector3.up);
        foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
        {
            var hitObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
            var damageable = hitObject.GetComponent<HealthSystem>();
            if (damageable != null && !alreadyHit.Contains(hitObject))
            {
                float damageToDeal = config.GetDamage();
                damageable.Damage(damageToDeal, config.GetElementalType());
                alreadyHit.Add(hitObject);
            }
        }
        startRaycast = endRaycast;
    }
}
```

I made a graph to better conceptualize what i made:

[image: Raycast Graph]

I use around 64 segments and a 50f raycast depth for the ground detection and it works/performs quite well (i noticed a 3-4ms increase in my older PC though).

But my question is: are there better approches to this? maybe i overdid something that could be done more easily.